# Write a file to SFTP using Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, ftp, oracle10g, sftp

I wrote a PL/SQL procedure to connect to an FTP server. I am able to write a file to that FTP server. Using the same code I tried to connect to an SFTP server, but it failed. How do I connect to SFTP using PL/SQL?

Comment: You can't perform SFTP from PL/SQL but you can using Java in Oracle. See [this article](http://dbashavefeelingstoo.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/sftp-with-plsql/) for an example of how it might be done.

Comment: That's not entirely true. You can use [`utl_http`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96612/u_http.htm) over an SSL protocol. It's not quite the same as SFTP but it's possible...

Comment: Thanks Ben - do you have any links to any articles about that? Is it straightforward? (not questioning, just curious) :)

Comment: @JeffreyKemp; sorry, I don't know of anything specific that's not proprietary. It's simple-ish, use `utl_http` to connect securely and `utl_file` to transfer the file in chunks over the connection.

Comment: Good original question.  I need this as well.  The gov't scenario I'm in they will not allow mapped drives so I need SFTP.  Just wondering if you ever gave John Doyle's recommendation a try http://dbashavefeelingstoo.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/sftp-with-plsql/  If so, did you run into any issues?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the commercial [ORA_SFTP](https://www.didisoft.com/ora-sftp/) package provided from DidiSoft:

```
connection_id := ORA_SFTP.CONNECT_HOST(...
ORA_SFTP.UPLOAD(connection_id, data, 'remote_file.dat');
```

*Disclaimer: I work for DidiSoft*

Answer (score 2):

SFTP requires SSH plus the implementation of a [protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13). As far as my PL/SQL knowledge reaches and Google's, there are currently no available implementation of SSH or this protocol in PL/SQL. There are some alternatives:

- Use Java in the database and open sufficient ports. Not recommended when this is the only reason to use Java in the database; it is not as well designed as PL/SQL and can be expensive to maintain by a DBA since most DBA's have no experience with it.
- Use PL/SQL to start a job outside the database. For instance, in the past I've used often [Pentaho Data Integration](http://community.pentaho.com/) (formerly known as Kettle) which provides a free solution to draw your data flow from table/procedure to sftp recipient and then run it. Running from PL/SQL requires a scheduler (I always used our own because it also integrates Kettle, but you can also consider the scheduler integrated with [Oracle Apps](http://www.oracle.com), [Redwood JCS/Cronacle](http://www.redwood.nl/solutions) or others). Coding in PL/SQL then becomes something like: 'begin package.submit('SFTP it'); package.wait; end;'.

I would go for the second option. If you need further details, please let me know.