# SFTP using Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, ftp, sftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a file into sftp using Oracle pl/sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209920/how-to-write-a-file-into-sftp-using-oracle-pl-sql)

i read through couple of articles and past posts here, but would like to see if Oracle had this feature included in any of their recent releases.

**Does Oracle database have any SFTP libraries or functions or utilities ?**

Comment: [Searching the documentation](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/search?word=sftp&partno=) suggests not, as do the previous answers here, though you can [roll your own](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11782580/266304). Have you read articles that suggest there is some built-in functionality?

Comment: @AlexPoole nope, i haven't read any article quoting about built-in functionality.. it's surprising.. since these articles talked about past oracle releases, i wanted to cross check if any recent oracle release included this feature.. looks like it's a NO .. thnx for the other pointers..

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @steve one of our oracle procedures will extract data from a table and create an excel/csv file out of it. This file needs to be transferred to a file server via SFTP. Rather than calling an UNIX sftp script or a Java program for SFTP, we were looking for an Oracle Native solution like the FTP library from oracle

Comment: This sounds like the wrong design. This is the job of a client program. Especially if you think about security domains.

Comment: @steve our client program is a web page. A button click in the web page has to invoke this oracle procedure which can extract data & place it as an csv/excel file in another file server. What would be your suggestion in this scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question - **Does Oracle database have any SFTP libraries or functions or utilities ?**

Answer - **No. There is for FTP but not SFTP.**